# Django dumpdata and loaddata not working for many-to-many intermediary model

Tags: django, serialization, model, many-to-many

I am using dumpdata with Django 1.2.3 on the following model:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    ...

class Foo(models.Model):
    bars = models.ManyToManyField(Bar, through="Foo_bar", blank=True, null=True)
    ...

class Foo_bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    ...
```

The json fixture serializes the bars associated with Foos in the Foo objects, resulting in an AttributeError when I try to run loaddata with the fixture:

```
AttributeError: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use App.Foo_bar's Manager instead.
```

Based on what I've [read](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8134), dumpdata may have been fixed to not serialize m2m, or loaddata fixed to properly deal with them, but it doesn't seem so. I've tried the --natural flag, still no luck. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. Why wouldn't it work with m2m fields? That seems fairly basic to me. Do you know any other way beside dumpdata that I can get my data inlcuding m2m fields in json format?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need to do with your fixtures, the command "[dumpscript](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dumpscript.html)" from the django_extension package is really useful for handling fixture with complex relations.
No primary keys are used in the file, it's just a python script which only uses objects, and as such can re-create your whole db simply using `object.save()` calls.

Comment: This doesn't the answer the question of what the problem is with dumpdata/loaddata. Are intermediary m2m models all that complicated?

Comment: looks like dumpscript also does not support m2m with intermediary models (issue 48)

Comment: I used it with this kind of fkey (through=...), the google code site is not updated, follow them on github...

Comment: As you can see in the code snippet in my original question, I am also using 'through=...'. Are you saying the code on github fixes Issue 48?