# Dumpdata with a many-to-many field in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm running a command to dump my database contents into json format:

`python manage.py dumpdata <appname>.<modelname> > file.json`

However, it is not dumping my many-to-many field which is called `category_id`. Well in fact, it is dumping it but the field is consistently empty. Why??

I have tried calling that table directly (which is a category mapping) as such:

`python manage.py dumpdata <appname>.<modelname_category_id> > file.json`

and I get the following error:

`Error: Unable to serialize database: Category matching query does not exist.`

I'm using Django 1.2.1 and SQLite backend.

Any hints?

UPDATE: I have tried deleting all rows in the modelname.category_id table, and even with only one row I still get this error.

The table is defined as follows
id: integer PRIMARY KEY
unipart_id: integer
category_id: integer

and both unipart_id and category_id fields are valid and exist.

Comment: What version of Django are you using? What backend db?

Comment: I updated the post with this info.

Comment: I think this means that some value you've entered for your `Category` model doesn't exist. Ensure that all the ids in the many-to-many relationship exist in their relevant tables? SQLite really doesn't validate your data much. I would suggest trying a mysql setup.

Comment: Ok that is a very high likelihood possibility.... Do you know why it would show the field as empty in the first case though? Same reason?

Comment: There is not enough information here to say. I would try doing a dump of everything (ainful as it might be) and see if it has data. Otherwise do a dump of model 1 and a dump of model 2. It may only come out on one model. `<appname>.<modelname_category_id>` shouldn't this be `<appname>.<firstmodelname>` or `<appname>.<secondmodelname>`?

Comment: Interesting -- according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698641/django-dumpdata-and-loaddata-not-working-for-many-to-many-intermediary-model) dumpdata in fact does not support M2M fields. But why?

Comment: When I do a dump of everything it still is blank in that field. When you say Model 1/Model 2, what do you mean exactly? What I mean by `modelname_category_id` is that the mapping of the `ManytoManyField` for that model seems to be stored in a separate table when I open the database...

Comment: You have to have two tables to map a many to many field to. One is `category` (as I can see you have a `category_id`) and the other is? That question you linked to is using an Intermediatry Model. Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 3):

I have two tables like below,

```py
from django.db import models


class AggregationCategories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "AggregationCategories"


class AggregationFunctions(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aggregation_category = models.ManyToManyField(
        AggregationCategories,
        related_name='aggregationfunctions_aggregationcategories'
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = "AggregationFunctions"
```

When you create many-to-many relationships, you'll get additional table the structure of `<model name>_<filed name>`. So according to my example `model name` is `AggregationFunctions` and the `field name` is `aggregation_category`. Based on that my additional table should be `AggregationFunctions_aggregation_category`. Yes, you can see all three tables in below picture.

[image]

So you can dump the data in third table like this, `python manage.py dumpdata <app name>.<third table name>`. So my `app name` is `catalogue` and the `third table name` is `AggregationFunctions_aggregation_category`. Based on that my command should be,

```sh
python manage.py dumpdata catalogue.AggregationFunctions_aggregation_category
```

---

If you've created many-to-many table using [ManyToManyField.through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through), [ManyToManyField.through_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields), for an example (directly took it from Django Official [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields)),

```py
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through='Membership',
        through_fields=('group', 'person'),
    )


class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    inviter = models.ForeignKey(
        Person,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="membership_invites",
    )
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Now you have a class call `Membership` for your many-to-many relationship, so you can use it same as before like this,

```sh
python manage.py dumpdata catalogue.Membership
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
appname.modelname_id_category
```

Answer (score 0):

Dump the data from the third table in a m2m relationship. Its name is `myapp_model1_model2`.

```
python manage.py dumpdata myapp.model1_model2 --indent 4 > fixtures/filename.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this topic as I was searching how to dump m2m site values from a table and nailed it. I'm on Django 4.

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
  title = models.CharField()
  sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
  ...
```

David's suggestion helped me find:

```
manage.py dumpdata --format json appname.MyModel_sites
```